# Getting one Roslyn syntax receiver per class

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I have a simple source generator defined as

```
[Generator]
public class NestedObjectGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
  public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
  {
    context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxReceiver());
  }
  public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
  {
    var recv = (MySyntaxReceiver)context.SyntaxReceiver;
    ClassDeclarationSyntax cds = recv?.Class;
    if (cds is null) return;

    // use cds here
  }

  private class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
  {
    public ClassDeclarationSyntax Class { get; private set; }

    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode node)
    {
      if (node is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds &&
        cds.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
      Class = cds;
    }
  }
}
```

I am running this generator on a file that has several partial classes in it. However, it seems that `Execute()` gets called only once, and the `Class` that is included is the class that has the `Main()` method, even though I have other classes in the file.

So, my question: how can I get `Execute()` to run once per affected syntax node, i.e., to get it to run once per partial class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your reciever like this:

```
private class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
  public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> ClassCandidates { get; } = new();

  public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode node)
  {
    if (node is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds && cds.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
      ClassCandidates.Add(cds);
  }
}
```

And then in the Execute method of the source generator you can loop on all the nodes you collected.
I got this approach from a really informative video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9Pv5IdinMU

Here is the github with the demos in the presentation, i learned this from these examples:

https://github.com/JasonBock/SourceGeneratorDemos

Comment: What about using the ISyntaxContextReceiver to process classes (and members) with attributes it cannot see yet as the generator also generates those attributes they use?